# mac 32 bit computers on mountain lion

Tags: osx-lion, 32bit-64bit, osx-mountain-lion

I'm thinking of supplying only a 64 bit target for mountain lion. But I think it also supports 32 bit processors. Are there still a lot of macs out there with 32 bits ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ML does not support any 32-bit computers. See http://www.apple.com/osx/how-to-upgrade/

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't even work with some 64-bit computers. BTW, remember that link will stop being useful before too long.